# do we get all (i.e. open / closed / merged) pull heads while doing a fetch with * configuration

Tags: eclipse, git, github

while checking out github pull heads through a * fetch configuration I retrieved a list of pull heads in the form of ref/pull/* or something similar.

Are these pointing to only open , closed or all pull requests ? and what about the pull requests that have been already merged and closed ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which git version you have installed.

It was true prior to git v2.0 build was changed from `match` to `simple`

V2. release notes:

> When "git push [$there]" does not say what to push, we have used the
>   traditional "matching" semantics so far (all your branches were sent
>   to the remote as long as there already are branches of the same name
>   over there).  In Git 2.0, the default is now the "simple" semantics,
>   which pushes:
>
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, and only
>     when the current branch is set to integrate with that remote
>     branch, if you are pushing to the same remote as you fetch from; or
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, if you
>     are pushing to a remote that is not where you usually fetch from.
>
> You can use the configuration variable "push.default" to change
>   this.  If you are an old-timer who wants to keep using the
>   "matching" semantics, you can set the variable to "matching", for
>   example.  Read the documentation for other possibilities.

---

### How does the push configuration related to pull request?

Git hub store the pull request using `refspec` which means that its behave just like any other branch with the exception that instead of begin placed under `/refs/heads/*` its is stored under `/refs/heads/<pulls (you can change this path- see below)>/*`.

So to summarize it:
Github pull reqauests behave the same way as normal refs, depending on your configuration. If you did changed anything and you using git<2 you will get the full list of pull request, if you changed the settings or using git>2 you should only get partial of the pull requests.

#### Example:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:xxx/xxxx.git
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

#### Fetch all the pull requests: (The **pr** folder is the one u defined above)

```
$ git fetch origin
From github.com:xxx/xxx
* [new ref]         refs/pull/<id1>/head -> origin/pr/<id1>
* [new ref]         refs/pull/<id2>/head -> origin/pr/<id2>
```

...